# Unmarshal unknown JSON fields without structs

Tags: go

I am trying to unmarshal a JSON object which has an optional array, I am doing this without an array and this is what I got so far:

```golang
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {

    jo := `
        {
            "given_name": "Akshay Raj",
            "name": "Akshay",
            "country": "New Zealand",
            "family_name": "Gollahalli",
            "emails": [
                "name@example.com"
                ]
        }
        `
    var raw map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jo), &raw)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Println(raw["emails"][0])

}
```

The `emails` field might or might not come sometime. I know I can use `struct` and unmarshal it twice for with and without array. When I try to get the index `0` of `raw["emails"][0]` I get the following error

```
invalid operation: raw["emails"][0] (type interface {} does not support indexing)
```

Is there a way to get the index of the `emails` field?

**Update 1**

I can do something like this `fmt.Println(raw["emails"].([]interface{})[0])` and it works. Is this the only way?

Comment: Yes, the only way to achieve what you want (without a struct) must include `raw["emails"].([]interface{})` at some point.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid a struct? A struct is the easy way to handle this--and no need to do it twice. If that field is missing, the struct will just have it unset.

Comment: @Flimzy I think I don't mind that now if I don't have to unmarshal it twice

Comment: Why the negative mark?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way is with a struct. There's no need to unmarshal twice.

```
type MyStruct struct {
    // ... other fields
    Emails []string `json:"emails"`
}
```

This will work, regardless of whether the JSON input contains the `emails` field. When it is missing, your resulting struct will just have an uninitialized `Emails` field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use type assertions. The Go tutorial on type assertions is [here](https://tour.golang.org/methods/15).

A Go playground link applying type assertions to your problem is [here](https://play.golang.org/p/nQY19CoN8La). For ease of reading, that code is replicated below:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    jo := `
        {
            "given_name": "Akshay Raj",
            "name": "Akshay",
            "country": "New Zealand",
            "family_name": "Gollahalli",
            "emails": [
                "name@example.com"
            ]
        }
        `
    var raw map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jo), &raw)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    emails, ok := raw["emails"]
    if !ok {
        panic("do this when no 'emails' key")
    }

    emailsSlice, ok := emails.([]interface{})
    if !ok {
        panic("do this when 'emails' value is not a slice")
    }

    if len(emailsSlice) == 0 {
        panic("do this when 'emails' slice is empty")
    }

    email, ok := (emailsSlice[0]).(string)
    if !ok {
        panic("do this when 'emails' slice contains non-string")
    }

    fmt.Println(email)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As always you can use additional libraries for work with your json data. For example with [gojsonq](https://github.com/thedevsaddam/gojsonq) package it will like so:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/thedevsaddam/gojsonq"
)

func main() {

    json := `
        {
            "given_name": "Akshay Raj",
            "name": "Akshay",
            "country": "New Zealand",
            "family_name": "Gollahalli",
            "emails": [
                "name@example.com"
                ]
        }
        `
    first := gojsonq.New().JSONString(json).Find("emails.[0]")
    if first != nil {
        fmt.Println(first.(string))
    } else {
        fmt.Println("There isn't emails")
    }

}
```